# Codeigniter, how do I use jwt library from third party folder in conjunction with models?

Tags: php, codeigniter, jwt

I have hit a bit of a conundrum.

I have installed https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt this library in my third_party folder with composer.

How would I utilise the `JWT::encode` from a model or controller with some parameters?

For example, I want to call `getToken($parameters)` model from a controller, and then that model load in that JWT library. I have googled this plenty but it seems my PHP knowledge is limited.

Answer (score 2):

Ok solved.

What you do is install third_party library. 
Autoload that into a new file in libraries folder like below.

```
<?php
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
{
        require_once(APPPATH . 'third_party/firebase-jwt/vendor/autoload.php');
        require_once(APPPATH . 'third_party/firebase-jwt/start.php');

}
class Firebasetoken { 
   function __construct($permissions = false) {

    $this->codeigniter_instance =& get_instance();
    $this->theToken = buildToken($permissions);
}

function get_firebase_token(){
    return $this->theToken;
}
```

In your start.php load in like this because namespace and CI dont play well apparently.

```
  <?php

    require_once 'jwt/src/BeforeValidException.php';
    require_once 'jwt/src/ExpiredException.php';
    require_once 'jwt/src/SignatureInvalidException.php';
    require_once 'jwt/src/JWT.php';

    use Firebase\JWT\JWT;
    function buildToken($permissions){
        //add example from jwt lib in here
    }
```

Then call it like this.

```
$this->load->library('FirebaseToken', $permissions);
$token = $this->firebasetoken->get_firebase_token();
```

Voila. 
Hope it saves someone time.